# How to contribute to apache?

Tags: apache, hadoop

I am an intermediate Java learner .I want to contribute to Apache Development,I saw there is a list of Apache Projects(like Hadoop,Derby etc),I have developed certain queries which I would like to get answered :-

1. what all Apache projects use Java ?
2. which apache project will be easier
   to start with for a beginner ?

Comment: List of Apache projects in Java: http://projects.apache.org/indexes/language.html#Java

Comment: I want to start contributing to Apache for Google Summer of Code , since I am a newbie , can you please suggest me which project will be suitable to work on ?

Comment: whichever project looks most interesting to you, talk to the dev team about joining GSoC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many Apache projects, include Hadoop, try to maintain a list of starter JIRAs to help new contributors become familiar with the code by fixing a simple, short issue.  This involves downloading the source, making a change, verifying correctness through tests, creating a patch, working with the community - all the skills you'll need to tackle more complicated issues.

Browse through [the list](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=labels%20%3D%20newbie%20and%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20and%20assignee%20%3D%20empty): and see if any interest you.